# Store and flow images into array

Tags: android, arrays, sorting, android-image

While I was writing code for a touch sliding gallery, I'm ended up in a dead end... or so it appears to me.
First i've stored some drawable into an array:

```
private int[] SeqImages = new int[] {
R.drawable.img1,
R.drawable.img2,
R.drawable.img3,
R.drawable.img4
};
```

Then I wrote this code to sort images:

```
...
imageView.setImageResource(SeqImages[position]);
((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
return imageView;
...
```

It works like a charm!
But... Foolish me! I need to make the same thing with images stored in a sd folder, and I'm a little lost. I've thought to list file like:

```
File imglista = new File("/path/of/my/pics");
String[] imginfolder = imglista.list();
```

Obviously this is not the solution... Someone have any better ideas?
THX to all.

Comment: `Obviously this is not the solution` why not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For getting all files from folder use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` for  SDCARD path instead of passing static String do it as:

```
 String root_sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
 imglista = new File( root_sd + "/images_path_on_sdcard" ) ;       
 File imginfolder[] = imglista.listFiles();
```

and make sure you have added SD-CARD permission in `AndroidManifest.xml` :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**EDIT:** for showing image in ImageView from SD-CARD do it as using `BitmapFactory.decodeFile`:

```
 Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imginfolder[position].getAbsolutePath());
 ...
 img_view.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: Yeah I've hardcoded only for this example... the problem is how sort through "imageView.setImageResource(SeqImages[position]);"

Comment: Ehy! That's marvellous!!! I was actually trying to use Bitmap, but I made some foolish errors! You're the man! Thx a lot!